# PSP34 Get Attribute Null Value

Tags: smart-contract, openbrush

I Already write code with openbrush.io and set Attribute on constructor here my code :

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
#![feature(min_specialization)]
        
#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod my_psp34 {
    
    // imports from openbrush
    use openbrush::traits::String;
    use openbrush::traits::Storage;
    use openbrush::contracts::psp34::extensions::mintable::*;
    use openbrush::contracts::psp34::extensions::enumerable::*;
    use openbrush::contracts::psp34::extensions::metadata::*;

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(Default, Storage)]
    pub struct Psp34Basic {
        #[storage_field]
        psp34: psp34::Data<Balances>,
        #[storage_field]
        metadata: metadata::Data,
    }
    
    // Section contains default implementation without any modifications
    impl PSP34 for Psp34Basic {}
    impl PSP34Mintable for Psp34Basic {}
    impl PSP34Enumerable for Psp34Basic {}
    impl PSP34Metadata for Psp34Basic {}
     
    impl Psp34Basic {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            let mut _instance = Self::default();
            _instance._mint_to(_instance.env().caller(), Id::U8(1)).expect("Can mint");
            let collection_id = _instance.collection_id();
            _instance._set_attribute(collection_id.clone(), String::from("name"), String::from("PSP34BASIC"));
            _instance._set_attribute(collection_id, String::from("symbol"), String::from("PSPB"));
            _instance
        }
    }
}
```

The code success to deploy, when i want to get attribute using PSP34 metadata get_attribute the value is null. Please help me how i retrieve symbol attribute or name ?

here i give image how i call the attribute?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, Already Know to Retrieve Symbol and name, create function

```
        //create function to get collection name and Symbol
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_collection_name(&self) -> String {
            self._get_attribute(self.collection_id(), String::from("name")).unwrap()
        }
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_collection_symbol(&self) -> String {
            self._get_attribute(self.collection_id(), String::from("symbol")).unwrap()
        }   

        //crate function _get_attribute
        fn _get_attribute(&self, collection_id: Id, key: String) -> Option<String> {
            self.metadata.get_attribute(collection_id, key) 
        }
```